# Как сделать кастомный spinner

Tags: android

Как сделать spinner как на картинке с категориями и подкатегориями? Может быть есть либа, которая поможет мне в этом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слушайте, ну это же базовые вещи, в каждом туториале есть. Что конкретно не получается.

Comment: Не понятно как сделать подкатегории

Comment: Spinner не предназначен для такой функциональности и с его помощью это не стоит и пытаться делать. Сделать это можно с помощью ExpandableListView

Comment: Вот и спрашивайте "как сделать подкатегории в спиннере", а не "как сделать спиннер".

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно, написано ведь - "С категориями и подкатегориями"

Comment: Можете взять готовую библиотеку, как, например, [эта библиотека](https://github.com/zaihuishou/ExpandableRecyclerview). Стрелочки можете заменить на свои галочки в ресурсах библиотеки. Или на  основе этой библиотеки сделать собственную реализацию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Открываете https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

2) Ищите инфу про класс **BaseAdapter**, нужен будет для реализации вложенности 
(категории \ подкатегории)

3) Реализуете свою custom-view, советую наследоваться через **RecyclerView** и кастомить через него, у него его адаптер лучше использовать, думаю поймете, разберетесь, информации о нем довольно много)